# Error Message Orthorectifying ASTER Imagery in ArcMap 10 with DEM

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, dem, orthorectification, aster

I am trying to orthorectify ASTER imagery (VNIR, 15m resolution) in ArcMap using an ASTER DEM  that I have downloaded from the GDEM website. The area is in the Andes, there are very high elevation differences so I guess orthorectification is needed.

I was using the tool "Create Ortho Corrected Raster Dataset (Data Management)" and I tried with the DEM as input and also with a derived DHM. I always get an error message very quickly.

It's the same coordinate system, I have chosen a very short path (C:/temp), I have tried with file formats *.img and *.tiff. I have never orthorectified before. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: ERROR 000425: Failed to create ortho-corrected raster dataset

Comment: Failed to execute (CreateOrthoCorrectedRasterDataset)

Comment: I read that error message now (sorry, hadn't thought about it) but no change --> I tried to save in a database without file extension and in a folder as *.tiff and *.img, still error message.

Comment: The usage reads "To orthocorrect a raster dataset, the raster must have RPCs associated with it." My guess is you don't have an input dataset with RPCs, and can't use that particular tool. Perhaps this document will give you other options: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000ms000000

Comment: yes, I saw that before but since in this specific tool RCPs weren't mentioned I hoped that it would work without. Are there possibilities to create RCPs in ArcMap or Erdas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error today. In my case, the problem was that I first pansharpened my satellite imagery, so it was put into the standard geodatabase. However, then the imagery was disconnected from the RPB file, which contains the RPC information. When applying the orthorectification tool on the original imagery, having the RPC file in the folder, it worked (it was a World View 4 image).

In the error description, did you read that "**When storing a raster dataset in a geodatabase, no file extension should be added** to the name of the raster dataset."